# не понимаю как вытащить данные дальше?

Tags: java, android, json, xml

```
public class Fragment_photo extends Fragment {

    private ImageView nameImage;
    private  Subject mSubject;
    private  Content content;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AssetManager mgr=getActivity().getAssets();
        ObjectMapper mapper= new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            InputStream inputStream;
            inputStream = mgr.open("numbers.xml");
            mSubject = mapper.readValue(inputStream, Subject.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo, container, false);

        nameImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.name_image);

      nameImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(??? ));
        return v;
    }


}
```

другой класс

```
public class Content {
    public  String signature;
    public  String photos;
    public  String sounds;
}
```

и еще один

```
public class Subject {
    public String name;
    public ArrayList<Content> content;
}
```

как теперь из mSubject  вытащить данные  и вставить в ImageView картинку? 
P.S.  как выглядят данные в mSubject ??
 сам файл

```
{
"name": "numbers",
"content": [{
"photos": "file:///android_asset/numbers/1.jpg",
"signature": "Один",
"sounds": "file:///android_asset/numbers/1.wav"
},
{
"photos": "file:///android_asset/numbers/2.jpg",
"signature": "Два",
"sounds": "file:///android_asset/numbers/2.wav"
}
]}
```

Comment: Если верить документации, то `mSubject` - это объект класса `Subject`. Наверное, у него есть какие-то поля и методы, к которым вы можете обратиться.

Comment: да есть поля public class Subject {
    public String name;
    public ArrayList<Content> content;
}
обращался так mSubject.questions,
 но мне надо оттуда вытащить например фото
 делал так 
 Content content= new Content();
       nameImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(content.photos));
 но видимо не так , так как ругается на пустую ссылку
 а как иначе не понимаю

Comment: @Сергей, добавьте весь код в тело вопроса. Дополните его так же тем, что проблема именно в выводе фото, а не просто значений JSON.

Comment: я понимаю что там null так как я просто обьявил переменную полем класса.  как тогда из mSubject вытащить ссылку и вставить в nameImage.setImageURI(Uri.parse(???)

Comment: Давайте разобьем вашу проблему на части: 1) Возможно Jackson "неправильно" разбирает ваш файл. Для ответа нам нужен образец вашего файла. 2) Uri.parse() делает что-то "не то". Для ответа нам снова нужен образец файла. 3) `setImageURI` не может загрузить вашу картинку. Для ответа не помешает собственно uri-картинки, т.е. опять хотелось бы увидеть образец файла :)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем проблема состоит из двух частей:

Во-первых, надо взять ссылку. После работы Jackson вы получите `Subject mSubject`, и для того файла, который вы привели, сработает такое:

```
String ref = mSubject.content.get(0).photos;
```

Естественно, надо проверять, что в списке есть элементы, возможно следует проверить наличие самого списка и вообще `mSubject`.

Во-вторых, полученную ссылку (`file:///android_asset/numbers/1.jpg`) не может обработать `imageView.setImageUri(..)`. Вернее он может, но будет искать файл в файловой системе, по пути `/android_asset/number/1.jpg` и не найдет, т.к. файл у вас скорее всего лежит в `assets`, где-то рядом с `numbers.xml`.

Насколько я понял, ссылки на `assets` вида `file:///android_asset/..` понимают только `WebView` и библиотека Picasso (там отдельный обработчик). Можно вынуть файл из Assets вручную, каким-то таким способом:

```
public class Fragment_photo extends Fragment {

    private ImageView nameImage;
    private  Subject mSubject;
    private  Content content;

    // новое поле для картинки
    private Drawable drawableView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        AssetManager mgr=getActivity().getAssets();
        ObjectMapper mapper= new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            // ваш код в onCreate
            InputStream inputStream;
            inputStream = mgr.open("numbers.xml");
            mSubject = mapper.readValue(inputStream, Subject.class);

            // достаем ссылку
            Uri imgUri = Uri.parse(mSubject.content.get(0).photos);

            // обрезка ссылки до состояния 'numbers/1.jpg'
            InputStream stream = mgr.open(
                imgUri.getPath().substring("/android_asset/".length())
            );
            drawableView = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, null);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_photo, container, false);

        nameImage = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.name_image);

      nameImage.setImageDrawable(drawableView);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Видимо вам надо сделать что-то типа такого:

```
try {
    InputStream inputStream;
    inputStream = mgr.open("numbers.xml");
    mSubject = mapper.readValue(inputStream, Subject.class);
    if (mSubject.content != null && mSubject.content.size() != 1) {
        content = mSubject.content.get(0);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**НО!** Как вы видите из кода, в списке может не оказаться элементов, это вам надо как-то обрабатывать и элементов в списке может быть больше 1 или 0, с этим тоже что-то надо сделать. Что именно я вам подсказать не могу, это зависит от логики приложения.

Comment: в списке всегда есть элементы. так как файл создаю руками и вношу туда данные тоже сам

Comment: @Сергей это сейчас, а в продакшене кто-то поправит руками и у вас всё сломается.

Comment: вы правы, прописал как вы сказали пишет : 
Unable to open content: file:///android_asset/numbers/1.jpg
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /android_asset/numbers/1.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
 хотя файл на месте лежит.